# Specifying DataTemplate for Live Charts Series

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, livecharts

I'm looking to build a Scatter plot with a best fit line using Live Charts.

Now the way I've been doing this is by having a `SeriesCollection` on the main view model like so, within the class of this interface I manually add the `BubbleSeries` and the `LineSeries` for the chart:

```
public interface IPointAnalysisViewModel : IAnalysisViewModel
{
    SeriesCollection Series
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

PointAnalysisViewModel:

```
foreach (var pointSliceViewModel in this.slices)
{
    this.series.Add(pointSliceViewModel.Series);
}
this.bestFitLineSeries = this.BuildBestFitLine(pointAnalysisModel.BestFitValues);
this.series.Add(this.bestFitLineSeries);
```

This series is then bound within xaml to the `Series` of the `CartesianChart` as follows:

```
<wpf:CartesianChart Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Series="{Binding Path=Series}" >
... UI Fluff
</wpf:CartesianChart>
```

Pretty basic as you'd expect, but this means that in my ViewModels for the series I then have know that the view will display a bubble series for me as follow:

```
public interface IPointSliceViewModel : IViewModel
{
    IBubbleSeriesView Series
    {
        get;
    }

    bool Show
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

To me this looks badly like some code 'smell' in that I need to know view specific objects within my View Model.

The only way that I can think that would allow me to separate the concerns of the View and the ViewModel is if I were able to provide the `CartesianChart` with the data templates for the `Series` and bind the `Series` to a collection of `IPointSliceViewModels` instead as follows:

```
<wpf:CartesianChart Grid.Column="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    SeriesSource="{Binding Path=Series}">
    <wpf:CartesianChart.SeriesTemplates>
        <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:PointSliceViewModel}>
            <wpf:BubbleSeries .../>
        </DataTemplate>
    </wpf:CartesianChart.SeriesTemplates>
... UI Fluff
</wpf:CartesianChart>
```

Which would simply allow me to have:

```
public interface IPointAnalysisViewModel : IAnalysisViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<IPointSliceViewModel> Series
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public interface IPointSliceViewModel : IViewModel
{
    ChartValues<ObservablePoint> Values
    {
        get;
    }

    bool Show
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Is it currently possible to provide the `DataTemplates` for the `Series` or do I have to manually do this in the code behind at the moment?

Or is there a different way of having potentially limitless numbers of series in a chart without having to define each of them in the View and without having to keep track of the view specific details in the VM?

Comment: You can't set a DataTemplate to a series, are you trying to show custom shapes as points in a bubble series? what are you trying to do, that forces you to try to pass a DataTemplate to a series?

Comment: I'm trying to add multiple series to the same `CartesianChart`, as I'd like to be able to show and hide each of the bubble points and then I'd also like to have a best fit line. The only way that I could do this was to control the series in each of my ViewModels but I feel it would be better to provide a data template for a `BubbleSeries` so that I can simply provide the values in the ViewModel, and bind the series in the `CartesianChart` to an array of the ViewModels.

Comment: You could also add many bubble series, even with only one point, then only change the visibility property of each series to control which points are visible

Comment: Currently this is what I am doing, I store the bubble series in the `IPointSliceViewModel` and in the `IPointAnalysisViewModel` concrete I bring all the bubble series together and add them to the `SeriesCollection`. But I feel that this is more complicated than it has to be as I'll have to know specifics (and controls specifics) of the view in the view model.